# Does less.css support exponents?

Tags: css, less

I'd like to use an exponent in less.css, in order to generate a series of fonts and save typing multiple multiplication operators.

Currently I'm just repeatedly multiplying by the same variable. This is ugly, but works:

```
h5 {
   font-size: @basefontsize * @goldenratio * @goldenratio;
}
```

Neither of the following pass the compiler:

```
h5 {
   font-size: @basefontsize ** @goldenratio;
}
```

or

```
h5 {
   font-size: @basefontsize ^ @goldenratio;
}
```

Is there any way I can use an exponent in less.css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the latest version of Less (1.5), you can just use `@basefontsize * pow(@goldenratio,2)`.

See the [Function Reference](http://lesscss.org/#reference).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to keep the answer up to date! I've marked this as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Pre LESS 1.5

Use the inline Javascript evaluation:

```
h5 {
   font-size: @basefontsize * (~`Math.pow("@{goldenratio}",2)`);
}
```